# Cordova File Plugin with InAppBrowser Plugin and File Opener Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a PDF file stored using File Plugin but I can't seem to open it with either InAppBrowser or File Opener Plugin. I'm using Visual Studio Emulator KitKat for Android.

Here's the codes for InAppBrowser Plugin. The `fileEntry.toURL()` method returns "file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.ionicblankapp/cache/Sample.pdf".

However, the InAppBrowser always displays a blank page.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
      dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false },
           function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(
                     function (fileWriter) {
                         fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                             var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileEntry.toURL(), '_blank');
                          };
                          fileWriter.write(fileBlob);
                });
       });
 });
```

For the File Opener Plugin, I get error status of "9" and this message

> Activity not found: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.ionicblankapp/cache/Sample.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x4000000 }"

Below is the codes for File Opener Plugin.

```
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
                            dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false },
                                function (fileEntry) {
                                    fileEntry.createWriter(
                                        function (fileWriter) {
                                            fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {    
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(fileEntry.toURL(), 'application/pdf', {
                                                success: function () {
                                                    //success
                                                },
                                                error: function (e) {
                                                    alert(e);
                                            });
                                            };
                                            fileWriter.write(fileBlob);
                                        });
                                });
                        });
```

Currently, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/simonprickett/pdfjscordova

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line

```
 var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileEntry.toURL(), '_blank');
```

to

```
 var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileEntry.toURL(), '_system');
```

Comment: I tried this, the InAppBrowser now doesn't even show up. :(